# Pegar foto de perfil do facebook e salvar no meu banco de dados?

Tags: php, javascript

Já estou conseguindo fazer o login com facebook mas não pego a foto da pessoa, como fazer isso?

Vi algumas coisas como ''https://graph.facebook.com/ID_user/picture

Mas como posso utilizar isso?

Comment: isso he um arquivo json he so vc faze o parse com jquery ou o php para pegar as informações q precisa

Comment: Evite postar links nas perguntas, poste o código do que você já tentou, ou a informação que é retornada por um link do web service por exemplo. Se tiver dúvidas em como elaborar sua questão, leia isso: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Eu fiz da seguinte forma:

```
               FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){
                    if(response.status == 'connected') {
                        FB.ui(obj, callback);
                    }
                    else {
                        FB.login(function(response){
                            if(response.status == 'connected') {
                                //Depois do login chamo o callback
                                FB.ui(obj, callback);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
                //Função do callback                    
                function callback(response) {
                    if(response.error_code == 4201)
                    {

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Como no post_id retornado vem a {id}_{post_id}, eu dou um split e pego a ID.
                        var ids = response['post_id'].split('_');
                        //Como eu usei o angular, fiz os comandos abaixo, mas se quiser apenas a id -> ids[0];
                        var appElement = document.querySelector('[ng-controller=FbController]');
                        var $scope = angular.element(appElement).scope();
                        $scope.$apply(function() {
                            $scope.addJson(ids[0]);
                        });
                    }
                }
```

Para pegar a foto eu usei a API `http://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/{{id}}/picture`